# AssertNull should be used or AssertNotNull

Tags: java, junit

This is a pretty dumb question but my first time with unit testing so:
lets say I have an object variable like obj and I want my unit test to Fail if this obj is Null.
so for assertions, should I say AssertNull or AssertNotNull ? I get confused how they are named.

Comment: @Gweebz, of course he could have tried both, but that's not the point. He's asking which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use `assertNotNull(obj)`. `assert` means `must be`.

Comment: "Assert means must be."  good thing. now they make sense. thanks

Answer (score 28):

The `assertNotNull()` method means "a passed parameter must not be `null`": if it is null then the test case fails.
The `assertNull()` method means "a passed parameter must be `null`": if it is not null then the test case fails.

```
String str1 = null;
String str2 = "hello";              

// Success.
assertNotNull(str2);

// Fail.
assertNotNull(str1);

// Success.
assertNull(str1);

// Fail.
assertNull(str2);
```

Answer (score 7):

`assertNotNull` asserts that the object is not null.  If it is null the test fails, so you want that.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add that if you want to write special text if It null than you make it like that

```
  Assert.assertNotNull("The object you enter return null", str1)
```

Comment: What needs to be imported in order to call that?

Answer (score 0):

In JUnit 4, IDEA (UE 2020) suggests using `assertThat(..., notNullValue());` instead of `Assert.assertNotNull(...)`.

For instance:

1. [IDEA warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QzkU.png)
2. [IDEA suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeOYe.png)
3. [IDEA fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XMXf.png)