# How to write assert notnull for the array list in junit

Tags: java, junit

I have ArrayList which contains student id's and this test code:

```
@Test public void studidtest() { 
   String arrdata={stud1 stud2 stud 3 stud 4 }; 
   for (i=0;¡<arrdata ; i++) { 
     assertNotNull(students.stdids).equals(arradata[i])
   }
```

This doesn't work - so how to write a correct test case?

Comment: Did you even google this? `Assert.assertNotNull`

Comment: Another answer to this question could be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123555/assertnull-should-be-used-or-assertnotnull

Comment: @prasanna Update your question with this information, do not put it into comments.

Comment: And I made some more updates to make that human readable ;-)

Comment: And feel free to remove all your comments that are no longer required then.

Comment: the code above is correct or not for assertnotnull and I added equals inside the assertnotnull @GhostCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off. You need to give some effort to show us how far you've come in your journey to solve the problem. It would be easier for us to write you the feedback you need to be able to LEARN anything of this question.

I'll starts as you'd never wrote any junit test class before.

you start up with your method.

```
@Test
public void testStudentId() {

}
```

Now, we need the test data. The easiest way is just to hard code it in, but if you've other alternatives, you can use it. To make it easier for my self, I just assume that i've some student data to go through.

```
    @Test
    public void testStudentId() {
       ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

now we need to go through every element of the arraylist.

```
    @Test
    public void testStudentId() {
       ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
       for (Student student: students) {
            Assert.assertNotNull(student);
       } 

    }
```

Wollah, you got it. It would be marked as an error if the student obj is null.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
@Test
public void testId(){
    List<User> users = getTestUsers(); // load your testUsers as you want.
    users.stream().map(User::getId).forEach(Assert::assertNotNull);
}
```